# Verb for bringing something from out of a state of completion?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say you are filling out a form. When you are done you can say, "I have completed this form."

It is in a state of **completion** because all of the required entries are filled out.

Now, let's say you need to make a few revisions, so the very first thing you do is to erase a field on the form. You've now brought this form to a state of "**incompletion**"

What verb adequately describes this notion of "to make incomplete?"

e.g. "When I erased this field I have ______ this form." (past tense example)

Something like this? "I have *uncompleted* this form."

Comment: The best verb for "to make incomplete" is *to make incomplete*. More typically you'd use *render*, though. By erasing a field you render the form incomplete.

Comment: Good thought- I like the consistency of "Rendered Complete" vs "Rendered Incomplete" and also fits nicely within software vernacular.

Comment: Your acceptance of 'invalidate' when you have made it plain that you're ' not meaning "completion" to mean that the form is "correct." ' is bewildering.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see your point. Semantically you're correct, but I didn't mean to be as restrictive, so I've removed that piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I erased this field I have **invalidated** this form.

**Invalidate**:

> deprive (an official document or procedure) of legal validity because it contravenes a regulation or law. *"a technical flaw in her papers invalidated her nomination"* — Google Dictionary

Also instead of saying it is completed, you could consider saying the form is  **validated** and then goes into a valid or invalid state.

Comment: Hey that's a great word! I think "invalidated" is definitely the best word for "uncompleting" a form. Although I may not say that a "completed" form is a "validated" form- but your point is well made. I would think an "incomplete" form could also be "validated" then go into an invalid state. (Neither here nor there- thanks for you answer)

Comment: Also, I'm using this form in a programming context, which makes "invalidated" fit really nicely within that vernacular.

Comment: It has to be pointed out that 'invalidated' is not a synonym for 'bring out of a state of completion. A form could be invalidated even if it wasn't previously in a state of completion, for example by filling in an erroneous value.

Comment: @DJClayworth, agreed it not perfect antoymn for completing, but reading between lines I thought OP could apply validate/invalidate to their scenario. I think there are a lot of state transitions that could be discussed here but likely ruled off-topic.

Comment: Invalidated is a legal/administrative term. A programming term for something made incomplete (like a line of code in a sequence) is truncate where something missing cuts the sequence in two or leaves off part of the sequence.

Comment: I think OP is developing web page forms where *validation/validated* terminology is the norm. Hence my suggestion for the 'opposite direction'. One example at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp

Comment: OP's 'Note that I'm not meaning "completion" to mean that the form is "correct." ' makes 'invalidate' a wrong answer.

Comment: *Withdrawn*?  "When I erased this field I have withdrawn this form."

Comment: Perhaps a xy problem in the original question http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377

Comment: Yes, I'm in a software UI forms context, but I wanted the question to be more broadly applicable. e.g. "I completed my spelling test homework," vs. "I invalidated my spelling test homework by erasing my name."

There's not really a whole lot of examples of this outside of software, since we make make changes to forms and documents so quickly that the word "edited" usually suffices for the whole "blanket operation".